# Remove imported package from Jupyter Notebook without restarting the kernel

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, seaborn

Is there a way to un-import a package from Jupyter Notebook without restarting the kernel?

**Why I Ask:**
I have a model that takes a long time to train. I am plotting some of the output of this model and when I imported seaborn it caused problems with the some of my plots. I would like to un-import seaborn without restarting the kernel and retraining the model.

I know there are workarounds like pickling the model and then replotting, but this situation got me curious about un-importing a package in Jupyter. Is that possible at all?

Answer (score 3):

I assume you want to restore the defaults of the rcParameters of matplotlib, rather than unimport another module. Even if you could unimport it, the plotting parameters would remain changed.

```
plt.rcdefaults()
```

Comment: Putting that right before my plt.show() fixed the issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

When using seaborn version 0.8, it should not interfere with your plots.

When using seaborn version 0.7 or below, you may `import seaborn.apionly` instead of `import seaborn` for the same effect. If you already have `import`ed `seaborn` see [@philippd's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45990244/4124317).